# How to resolve relations in a query for JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have 2 tables, **Jedis** and **Padawans**, with a many to many relationship through a third table, **Apprenticeship**. their app/models rb files define their relations like this:

Jedi:

```
class Jedi < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :apprenticeships
  has_many :padawans, :through => :apprenticeships
end
```

Padawan:

```
class Padawan < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :apprenticeships
  has_many :jedis, :through => :apprenticeships
end
```

Apprenticeship:

```
class Apprenticeship < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :jedi_id, :padawan_id
  belongs_to :jedi
  belongs_to :padawan
end
```

When I query like this:

```
@apprenticeships = Apprenticeship.where(jedi_id: 1)
```

And return the results to the front-end as JSON:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: @apprenticeships }
end
```

The JS ajax call that initiated the request receives an array of objects, each representing an apprenticeship record.  Each object looks like this (stringified):

```
"{"id":1,"created_at":"2016-10-25T04:42:24.020Z","updated_at":"2016-10-25T04:42:24.020Z","jedi_id":1,"padawan_id":1,"apprenticeship_status":null}"
```

At this point in the process, I would prefer the apprenticeship records to be this instead (with ids resolved to objects):

```
"{"id":1,"created_at":"2016-10-25T04:42:24.020Z","updated_at":"2016-10-25T04:42:24.020Z","apprenticeship_status":null,"jedi":{"id":1,"name":"Yoda"},"padawan":{"id":1,"name":"Luke Skywalker"}}"
```

What is the correct, cleanest method of accomplishing this using only Ruby - so JS can receive the proper array of objects to work with?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can probably ask your `#to_json` to include methods `jedi` and `padawan`, which are also methods on your model instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you transform the object to_json, try using:

`@apprenticeships.to_json(include: [:jedi, :padawan])`

Comment: Awesome.  This appears to be partially correct, but it does not include both table records.  In the case of `@apprenticeships.to_json(include: :jedi, include: :padawan)` only padawans are included, and for `@apprenticeships.to_json(include: :padawan, include: :jedi)`, only jedis.

Comment: Try `@apprenticeships.to_json(include: [:jedi, :padawan] )`

Comment: That did it, thank you greatly.  Would you mind updating your answer before I select it as best answer?